# How Scan Values with colon ":" from a Dynamodb Table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am facing a similar problem, using boto3 the query does not work, while it works on console.

First I tried this scan without success:

```
text = 'city:barcelona'
filter_expr = Attr('timestamp').between('2020-04-01', '2020-04-27')
filter_expr = filter_expr & Attr('text').eq(text)
table.scan(FilterExpression = filter_expr, Limit = 1000)
```

Then, I notice that for a `text` variable that does not contain ":", the scan works.
So, I tried this second scan using ExpressionAttributeNames and ExpressionAttributeValues

```
table.scan(
            FilterExpression = "#n0 between :v0 AND :v1 AND #n1 = :v2",
            ExpressionAttributeNames = {'#n0': 'timestamp', '#n1': 'text'},
            ExpressionAttributeValues = {
                ':v0': '2020-04-01', 
                ':v1': '2020-04-27', 
                ':v2': {"S": text}},
            Limit = 1000
            )
```

Failed again.

By the end, if I change in the first example:

- `text = 'barcelona'`
- `filter_expr = filter_expr & Attr('text').contains(text)`

I can get the records. IMO, it is clear that the problem is the  ":"

Is there another way to search by texts with ":" character?

Comment: Both examples work correctly for me with `text` and `timestamp` as string fields. I changed `':v2': {"S": text}` to `':v2': text` because you're using resource level scan so you don't need to supply the low-level attribute type. Check you have an up to date boto3 library.

Comment: If you escape the colon, does your code work?: `text = 'city\:barcelona'`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @jarmod. I was testing it directly inside of AWS Lambda with Python (3.8) and boto3 (1.12.22). But today, when I run the test with a print to get the boto version, it worked without modification! I don know if it was some instability of the read capacity o another thing.

Comment: Hi @g_sexton, thank you for the suggestion, yesterday I tried to put a '\', but did not work. But as I answered before, now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[writing an answer so that we can close out the question]

I ran both examples and they worked correctly for me. I configured `text` and `timestamp` as string fields. Check you have an up to date boto3 library.

Note: I changed `':v2': {"S": text}` to `':v2': text` because you're using [resource](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html) level [scan](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.scan) and you don't need to supply the low-level attribute type (it's only required for [client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/clients.html) level [scan](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.scan)).